# Almost orthogonality in $L^p$ norm for functions with disjoint Fourier support?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis

Given a sequence of functions $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}\subset \mathcal S(\mathbb R^n)$, whose Fourier support are pairwise disjoint, i.e.
$$\text{supp}(\hat f_m)\cap \text{supp}(\hat f_n)=\emptyset,\ \ \ m\neq n$$
where $\mathcal S(\mathbb R^n)$ denotes the Schwartz functions.

From Plancherel's theorem we know that for the case $p=2$,
$$\sum_{i=1}^N||f_n||_{L^2}^2=||\sum_{i=1}^Nf_n||_{L^2}^2$$
But whether similar results hold for the case $1<p<\infty$, we would expect the form of
$$c\sum_{i=1}^N||f_n||_{L^p}^p\leq||\sum_{i=1}^Nf_n||_{L^p}^p\leq C\sum_{i=1}^N||f_n||_{L^p}^p$$
I could construct counter examples for the left inequality of the case $2<p<\infty$,and the right inequality of the case $1<p<2$, so it remains to prove or disprove the following two inequalitys:
$$c\sum_{i=1}^N||f_n||_{L^p}^p\leq||\sum_{i=1}^Nf_n||_{L^p}^p,\ \ \ 1<p<2$$
$$\left\Vert\sum_{i=1}^Nf_n\right\Vert_{L^p}^p\leq C\sum_{i=1}^N||f_n||_{L^p}^p\ \ \ 2<p<\infty$$
Any advise would be appreciated.